# Acess shared directory in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, soapui

**So this is the current situation :**

I'm using java to run some groovy (with SoapUI)
In my groovy code, I access a windows shared directory to get some file, and also to store some other.
After I've done everything, the groovy code will create and Excel sheet containing the links to those file.

**Now the problem :**

My code works fine when I execute my java program :
to access those file (in the groovy code) I'm using :
 `////ip/folder1/folder2/ ...` (Thanks stackoverflow)

But when I'm putting the whole thing in jenkins I get an error saying that no file were found :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\ip\folders
```

- Locally the error shows the correct link
- In the server it shows a link like this : 
  `/etc/home/someFolder/jenkins////ip ...`

**Solutions :**

The easiest one is to make Jenkins treat my links as I code them
I found a plugin that can deal with shared directory (publish overs CIFS), but it's not really what I seek because all magic happens inside of the code.

Thanks !

Comment: Mount the remote machines directory to jenkins machine.

Comment: Thank you but I don't have access to the jenkins machine